# Complex Analysis proof problem

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I have an feeling this bad proof because I am assuming my conclusion and I go into repeating. This isn't allowed in mathematics, so I need help to refix my steps.

So the proof I am proving is |ab| = |a||b|

So I started with:

Let a,b $\in \mathbb{C}$

I claimed $|ab|^{2} = |a|^{2} |b|^{2}$ is true

so I went to from LHS = RHS (to say LHS is equal to RHS) by using modulus of complex which is $|z|^{2}$ = $zz^{*}$

$|ab|^{2} = aa^{*} (bb^{*})$ = $(ab)(ab)^{*}$ = $|ab|^{2}$

then i took the square root of $|ab|^{2} = |a|^{2} |b|^{2}$ to give me |ab| = |a||b| because modulus is never negative, and we only take the positive.

this is where I believe this proof is 100% written wrong because I am assuming my claim is true (unproven to be exact) and it repeats again. How do I fix this?

Comment: This proof is actually fine, it's not circular to start with $|z|^2 = z z^*$ and then do algebra, or to take the positive square root because the modulus is nonnegative.

Comment: You are safe because $||ab|| = |ab|$ and $||a||b|| = |a||b|$.  If you hadn't known that we were dealing with non-negative numbers and we had $||ab|| = ||a||b||$ we'd be stuck as we couldn't claim $||a||b|| = ||a||\cdot||b||$ but we are claiming no such thing.  We are only claiming $|a|\cdot |b| = |a|\cdot |b|$ which it obviously is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$|ab|^{2}=(ab)(ab)^{*}=aba^{*}b^{*}=(aa^{*}) (bb^{*})=|a|^{2}|b|^{2}$. Now take square root.

Comment: what step I take the square root, this is where I am confused. Can you show me it? 

do I have to prove LHS = RHS? And is it fine so far what I did or is 100% bad.

Comment: @EM4 you did not use commututivity of complex multiplication after getting $(ab)(a^{*}b^{*})$ and that is why you just got $|ab|^{2}=|ab|^{2}$. You should write $(ab)(a^{*}b^{*})$ as $(aa^{*})(bb^{*})$ which is $|a|^{2}|b|^{2}$ and then take square root.

Comment: so I have to state commutativity before I go to the next step. Then I take the square root of the entire equation I claimed its true?

Comment: @EM4 Yes, commutativity is the main step in this proof.

Comment: so I proved the right hand side by the left hand side and square left hand side and right hand side? 

so what I did earlier was wrong due to missing commutativity.

Comment: @EM4 Yes, that is right.

Answer (score 3):

Write those numbers in polar form, that is
$$
a=re^{i\theta}\\
b=se^{i\phi}\;.
$$
Since
$$
ab=rse^{i(\theta+\phi)}
$$
and $|a|=r$, $|b|=s$ and $|ab|=rs$, you reach the conclusion easily

Answer (score 2):

You are not assuming what you are trying to prove.  You are assuming two *other* things.

You are assuming:

1. That $(mn)^2 = m^2n^2$ for all $m,n\in \mathbb C$.  Which I believe is a valid assumption.

ANd that

2. If $x,y$ are non negative reals then $x^2 = y^2 \iff x=y$ which is valid presuming it was proven earlier that $f:[0,\infty)\to [0,\infty)$ via $f(x) = x^2$ is an injective function (presumably it was so proven by proving $f(x)$ is strictly increasing).

Then $|ab|^2 = (|a||b|)^2 = |a|^2|b|^2$ does imply that $|ab| = |a||b|$.

I think you are confusing that you seem to think defining $\sqrt {m^2} = |m|$ somehow makes $\sqrt{(ab)^2} = |ab|$ seem to assume $|ab| =|a||b|$. But it doesn't.

You are assuming $|ab|$ and $|a|$ and $|b|$ are non-negative so $\sqrt{|ab|)^2} = |ab|$ and not necessarily $\big ||ab|\big|$ and $\sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2} = |a||b|$ and not $\big||a||b|\big |$.

If you had concluded that $\sqrt{|ab|^2} =\big ||ab|\big|$ and that $\sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2} =\big||a||b|\big |$ then we would have $\big ||ab|\big|=\big||a||b|\big |$ and you'd have gotten nowher as you'd have no way to prove $\big||a||b|\big |=\big||a|\big |\big||b|\big|$.

But that's moot as we are dealing the strictly non-negative numbers and proving $\sqrt{|ab|^2} = |ab|=\sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2} = |a||b|$ ***is*** .... proving $\sqrt{|ab|^2} = |ab|=\sqrt{|a|^2|b|^2} = |a||b|$